# Do XAML objects remain virtually present when leaving a XAML page in Windows 8 App?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, mvvm-light

I use the MVVM Light Toolkit to define the association between the view-model and the view.

The container is instructed to register a view-model as a singleton instance. Thus, the same instance will always be returned when the GagaViewModel is required:

```
public GagaViewModel GagaViewModel
{
    get
    {
        var vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GagaViewModel>();
        vm.Setup(); //Clear the ObservableCollection
        return vm;
    }
}
```

You can click on a thumbnail item on PriorGaga.xml. The self-chosen item is then selected in the GridView "MyGridView" in Gaga.xaml. Code-behind file of Gaga.xaml:

```
protected override async void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    var itemId = navigationParameter as String;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("navigationParameter was either null or empty");
    }

    await ((GagaViewModel)DataContext).Init(itemId); //Busy(-Indicator) while loading data from server, filling the ObservableCollection and writing the selected item down

    BringItemIntoView();
}

private void BringItemIntoView()
{
    var vm = (GagaViewModel)DataContext;

    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () => MyGridView.ScrollIntoView(vm.SelectedItem));
}
```

That works fine. As a sample: Item #45 appears within the viewport immediately (correct **viewport** position from the beginning).

But when you click the back button and return to Gaga.xaml by selecting an arbitrarily thumbnail item (let's just say #29), you will see item #1 and then the switch to #29 (the **viewport** is moving over the **container**). Do someone know what's going on under there? Are there any virtualized items in the container from the preceding Gaga.xaml visit?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the lifespan of the instance of your Gaga page is determined by its `NavigationCacheMode` property. By default, it is set to `Disabled`. Assuming that you haven't changed this property, you should be seeing a new instance of your Gaga page every time you navigate to it. You can verify this behavior by setting a breakpoint in its constructor. Consequently, I would think that each time you navigate to Gaga, the behavior of the UI should be identical, because everything is fresh.

(I wanted to add this as a comment, since I haven't actually answered your question, but sadly I do not have enough rep. I apologize in advance; please do not smite me down!）